# ERROR- Gateway reported of successful transaction but it's response came from the IP that is not specified in the list of valid IPs:

Tags: php, paypal, payment, gateway

AS the title says...

We are using X-Cart and their X-Payments connector to PayPal. In looking at the error logs, I'm seeing the same error for all transactions:

```
[13-Jul-2015 10:13:33] CHECKOUT message:
    Payment processing notice.
    Login: 
    IP: 173.20.000.00
    ----
    Payment method: Credit or Debit card
    bill_output = Array
    (
        [sessid] => d30672a088117bb334fa56hytgfed456
        [code] => 3
        [billmes] => Gateway reported of successful transaction but it&#39;s response came from the IP that is not specified in the list of valid IPs: 173.20.000.00
    -- response ----
    Payment is charged
    (last 4 card numbers: 1234);
    (card type: MC);
```

The IP is shows is always the customers IP address.

We are using PayPal Payments Pro to take the credit cards.

So, what are the IP address that are "valid"?

I went here and got a list of IP address, but I'm cunfused if this is what I need, and which one to use.

https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/92/session/L3RpbWUvMTQzNjgxNjg3OC9zaWQvVUFBWW1ocm0%3D

Comment: Have you asked your vendor? Tough to guess - e.g. your vendor systems "whitelist" of Paypal IPs, PayPal Manager (aka Payflow) IP restrictions setup, etc.

Comment: I've been in email talks with PayPal. They said it's not their error. So I generated a support ticket with X-Cart. They said the error is on PayPal's end. Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may be due to blocked IP's in your PayPal Manager account. Log in to PayPal Manager and under account administration and then manage security, you will see links for allowed IP's. IP's that you have entered in there could be causing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you mentioned is not thrown by PayPal. In-fact there is no IP address returned in the [Dodirectpayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) API request calls .It could be that you have setup `Fraud Management Filters` to restrict few IP addresses inside your paypal account or your server is throwing that error message even though the transaction was successful.